# Laravel selected, auto selected value based on user group_id

Tags: laravel

hello i have created a form which had an selected option value for `group_id` like for example :

[image]

but there was some user which they already had an `group_id`, and i was planning to make the user which they already had their own `group_id` only able to choose and select their own `group_id`, and also the select option value only shown their own `group_id`, here what i have been done so far :

```
<div class="row mg-t-20">
    <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Group Sales:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 mg-t-10 mg-sm-t-0">
        <select name="group_id" class="form-control select2" @if(auth()->user()->group_id) readonly @endif>
            @if(auth()->user()->group_id)
                    <option value="{{auth()->user()->group_id}}">{{ $group->id}}</option>
            @elseif(!auth()->user()->group_id)
                    <option label="Choose Group..."></option>
                @foreach($groups as $group)
                    <option value="{{ $group->id }}">{{ $group->id }}</option>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

i managed to catch user `auth()->user()->group_id` or `group_id` in hidden value to make sure the data is being catch here, so far i only managed to catch user `group_id` only and the option value remain the same, can someone provide a solution?, thanks!.

Comment: Sorry, it's not quite clear what your wanting. What's the issue with the select?

Comment: sorry i will try to explain as much as i can, i want to create a `select` value which contain `group_id`, but i want to make the select `group_id` for those user who already had their own `group_id` only able to select their own specific `group_id`, for example mine was `group_id` '4', and i want to make the `select` value only containt my `group_id` not other groups, apologize for my english.

Comment: I take it that the above code is showing all the group_ids even when a user already has one set?

Comment: for the first `@if` yes, but for the `@elseif` is for user who doesn't have a `group_id` like admin who dont have `group_id`, so the first one is to check whether user had `group_id` or not.

Comment: Firstly, the `elseif` could just be changed to `else` considering that it's the exact opposite of the `if` condition and you don't have any other `else` statements. Secondly, if the check (`auth()->user()->group_id`) isn't working, it would suggest that you either don't have a logged in user, there isn't a field on the user called `group_id` or that user simply doesn't have `group_id` What do you get if you run `dd(auth()->user()->group_id);`? Also, is the `group_id` field definitely part of the `users` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if they're already assigned to a group, you want them to only be able to select their group in the dropdown, but if they're not already assigned to a group then you want them to be able to select any group?

In which case, it's something like this you're after (although I'm not sure why your existing code isn't getting you there, although it's a little convoluted) :

```
<?php $existing = Auth::user()->group_id ?>
<select name="group_id" class="form-control select2" @if($existing != "") disabled @endif>
@if($existing != "")
    <option value="{{ $existing}}" selected>{{ $existing }}</option>
@else
<option label="Choose Group..."></option>
    @foreach($groups as $group)
        <option value="{{ $group->id }}">{{ $group->id }}</option>
    @endforeach
@endif
</select>
```